# OTA (over the air) acronyms

Tags: java, applet, smartcard, javacard, ota

I am working on Java Card (SIM) and I am using OTA Technology. There are some expressions that I do not have a good definition for them.

For instance, when I load an applet on SIM (Subscriber Identity Module), I use BIP or SMS. I know about SMS. But what is BIP?

I appreciate if anyone could describe the following expressions for me:

1. RFM & RAM
2. TAR
3. DAP
4. BIP

I know that TAR stands for Toolkit Application Reference but I would like the meaning explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the correct answer to these questions. I want to share it. I hope I can help.

1. **RFM** stands for Remote File Management.
   **RAM** stands for Remote Application Management.

Both of them are a standard mechanism for remote management of files or Applications(for java card like SIM)--->more information ETSI TS 102 225,226.

2. **TAR** stands for Toolkit Application Reference

This is a form of identification that specifies who can take this package on destination (for destination identification).

To be addressed, the Toolkit Application needs a first-level application (e.g. GSM, USIM application). More information on TAR can be found in ETSI TS 102 220.

3. **BIP** stands for Bearer Independent Protocol

It is a mechanism by which the terminal provides the UICC with access to the data bearers supported by the terminal and the network.

This feature enables a UICC to establish a data channel through the handset to a remote server in the network. Depending on UICC / ME capabilities BIP can handle up to 7 open data channels at the same time. For more information ETSI TS 102 223 and Interoperability Stepping Stones (this is a SIM Alliance document).

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, DAP is missing in action in your explanation.

Comment: I have formatted your answer, please take a look at the changes when it comes to markdown. Markdown is a really easy formatting language to learn. You can look at the changes by hitting [edited xxx ago] above my name or, to see the raw text, just by hitting the edit button.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I don't know what does DAP exactly means. when I found the answer, I will share it.

Comment: Suggestion: :You can add ATR also. That is very basic and will be good add-on here.

Answer (score 0):

**DAP** stands for Data Authentication Pattern

It is defined by GlobalPlatform.
The DAP key is either a symmetric or asymmetric key pair. If asymmetric, the public key is loaded into the SSD and the private key kept secret for signing the application code by the Application Provider.

The use of the DAP is optional. If used, a hash is applied to the Load File Data Block for ensuring integrity of the data and a signature (or MAC) is applied to the hash for authenticity of the origin.